# Google Sheet sumif based on month and year

Tags: google-sheets

I am learning Google Sheet and I am trying to create my own sheet to track expenses.

I have 1 drop down cell with date years (2022) and one cell with drop down with month (full name as in January)

I want to select the month and year and want to show all my expenses based on the selected year and month.

I have the month working, but I don't know how to integrate the year.
What I know Is that my current code is using sumif, which only allows 1 criteria. So I should use "&" to add the year. ... but how?

> ={{ArrayFormula(sumif(ArrayFormula(text(Transacties!A2:A15;"MMMM"));  unique(ArrayFormula(text(F2;"MMMM"))); Transacties!C2:C15))}}

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps Stack Exchange! I don't fully understand your formula, but this seems like a job for [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula repeats `arrayformula()` and is enclosed in two superfluous [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276). It can be simplified to:

`=arrayformula( sumif( text(Transacties!A2:A15, "MMMM"), text(F2, "MMMM"), Transacties!C2:C15 ) )`

To match both year and month, use `filter()`, like this:

`=sum( filter( Transacties!C2:C, text(Transacties!A2:A, "yyyyMMMM") = F2 & G2 ) )`